# Nested function inside for loop function | add/remove class | keyframes animation

Tags: javascript, for-loop

hi I have a for loop that is counting from 1 till infinity and I would like to change a background of a div and colour of the 'p'every time number is updated. It works when I make loop once (means for a first change but it does not rum animation for a second time. (numbers keep updating)

```
   <div class="section" id="box">
      <p id="demo">23375</p>
  </div>
```

my CSS

```
.section {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.pargraph-active,
.colorTransition {
  animation: colorTransition 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes colorTransition {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
  50% {
    color: white
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

and JS

```
let box = document.querySelector('#box');
let demo = document.querySelector('#demo');

function runAnimation() {
  box.classList.add('colorTransition');
  demo.classList.add('pargraph-active');
  console.log(`Animation started`);
}

function initialState() {
  box.classList.remove('colorTransition');
  demo.classList.remove('pargraph-active');
  console.log(`Initial State`);
}

(function theLoop(i) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      demo.innerHTML = i;
      if (i++) {
        theLoop(i);
      }
      runAnimation();
    },
    2000,
    initialState()
  );
})(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some error in @keyframe syntax, you are missing `}` and also `;` after color.

I fixed it and it work now, but i suggest that you only use css instead .

something like this would do

```
animation: colorTransition 2s ease-in-out infinite;
```

```js
let box = document.querySelector('#box');
let demo = document.querySelector('#demo');

function runAnimation() {
  box.classList.add('colorTransition');
  demo.classList.add('pargraph-active');
  console.log(`Animation started`);
}

function initialState() {
  box.classList.remove('colorTransition');
  demo.classList.remove('pargraph-active');
  console.log(`Initial State`);
}

(function theLoop(i) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      demo.innerHTML = i;
      if (i++) {
        theLoop(i);
      }
      runAnimation();
    },
    2000,
    initialState()
  );
})(1);
```

```css
.section {
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: blue;
}

.pargraph-active,
.colorTransition {
  animation: colorTransition 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes colorTransition {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
    }
  50% {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="section " id="box">
      <p id="demo">23375</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: hey, that is not an issue because now you created the infinite animation that it's not invoke by change of of number but it's going on it's own. It will be the easier to see when you leave animation for 2s and then give 5s. delay for function. It will not be synchronous.

Comment: Well sorry i was supposed to add it as an example, and not include it in the css:) but i have fixed your problem now anyway, so you should mark this as answer :)